# Magento 2.3 EE: Can't able to run installation

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, installation

I'm very new to Magento, i have Magento_2.3-EE, I'm using Ubuntu-16.4, I created a virtual host, extract Magento_2.3 folder in it, now when i type and hit URL `mg.local`, i get blank white page...

Also when i type this command to switch to developer mode `sudo php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer` i get this error `There are no commands defined in the "deploy:mode" namespace.`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check /var/log/ for the error

Comment: their is no /var/log/ .... @SaphalJha

Comment: is your front-end working?

Comment: I'm trying to install Magento-2.3 brother, i get this issue while installing....

Comment: @SaphalJha now installation started, don't know what happend but i was trying to hit `mg.local/` but when i type `mg.local/setup` installation started...

Comment: ohk, then your htaccess file is not working.

Comment: i don't have `.htaccess` in root folder...

Comment: You should add .htaccss file

Comment: yeah when i extract magento folder, i dosen't extract properly....

Comment: ok, Now it will work correctly.

Comment: Yup, Thanks for your time....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like htaccss file is missing.

Comment: Bro @SaphalJha please help me out https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/276387/magento-2-custom-js-not-working-when-adding-more-than-1-js