# Magento 2: jQuery Datatables Button Extentions Not Working

Tags: magento2, javascript, custom, phtml, requirejs-config.js

**============================UPDATED 1.1============================**

I'm new to `Magento 2.3`, I'm trying to apply jQuery DataTable(DONE), after than, I want to add it's Button Extension, for that i need to add two more `js`, i did, now my Js file in included but can't see print button, Here is my code:

**`/EC/Downloads/view/adminhtml/requirejs-config.js`**

```
 var config = {
    map: {
   '*': {
       dataTables: 'EC_Downloads/js/datatables.min'
     }
   }
 };
```

**`/EC/Downloads/view/adminhtml/templates/test.phtml`**

```
<script>
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui','dataTables'], function($){ 
    $(document).ready(function($){
        $('#example').DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
            'print'
        ]
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**Initializing other two js `button.js`, `button_print.js` like this:**

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "EC_Downloads/js/buttons":{},
            "EC_Downloads/js/buttons_print":{}
        }
    }        
</script>
```

Getting This Error:
[image]

Comment: Have you done setup upgrade, static-conetent deploy and cache flush?

Comment: i didn't do upgrade as i think its not necessary, but did `sudo rm -rf var/ pub/static/adminhtml generated/` `sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile`, `sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` & `Clean` `Flush`....

Comment: still your file not included?

Comment: Nope, No Js in Network....

Comment: i cant see how you use dataTables ?

Comment: @magefms i did it like this see my answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/275978/jquery-datatables-js-how-to-apply-it-on-admin-grid

Comment: @magefms question updated....

Comment: @RutveeSojitra question updated....

Comment: These 2 scripts "EC_Downloads/js/buttons", "EC_Downloads/js/buttons_print" will require proper path of EC_Downloads/js/datatables.min which you need to update it manually. by default it will be define(["jquery","datatables.net"]

Answer (score 0):

I've used dataTables before in frontend theme.  Not that different to what you have tried.  Just for clarity here's what I ended up with.

```
require(['jquery', 'jquery.dataTables'], function($, DataTable) {
```

app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/requirejs-config.js

```
    {
        "jquery.dataTables": "Magento_Theme/js/jquery.dataTables.min"
    },
```

Location of file

`app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/web/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js`

Worked for me.

Comment: Bro @DominicXiegen dataTable is working for me, the problem is i just want to add Button Extention `https://www.datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/simple.html` which is not working.....

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your `<script>` tag with below code

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init" />
```

Refer: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html

Comment: could you show me how i use it in my code ???

Comment: not working, your code not working in `.phtml`

Comment: gettting the same error?

Comment: i'm getting a syntax error, my datatable works perfectly just want to add buttons for print :( https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/simple.html

Comment: Please see updated question, i initialize other two JS and getting error in console.... @SaphalJha